# Why was Boba Fett still hanging around with Jabba?

Tags: star-wars

Boba Fett fell into the the Sarlacc Pit in *Return of the Jedi* due to the rather clumsy actions of a blind Han Solo and being on Jabba the Hutt's barge in the first place.

But why was Boba still in the company of Jabba the Hutt?  He's a bounty hunter and one that has no compunctions with working for anyone, be they Hutt or Imperial.

**Why did he stick around and wait for the rebels to come mount a daring rescue?**

Comment: Didn't you see the dancing girl he was flirting with?

Comment: A related question would be - why was Boba Fett with Jabba in Mos Eisley in Episode IV?

Comment: @RichardVenable What?  Jabba never showed up in episode IV.  What are you talking about?  ;p ((Good question though.  I suspect the answer will probably be similar to Null's answer below))

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Tales from Jabba's Palace* directly suggests Boba Fett stuck around to collect bounties on Chewbacca, and possibly the other rebels.

Upon delivering Han Solo, the bounty hunter has this exchange with Jabba:

> "There is news," Jabba continued, "that Vader failed to capture Skywalker, that Organa and Calrissian escaped him as well . . . and that Chewbacca is likewise free. Their combined bounties are . . . impressive." Heavy-lidded eyes examined Fett. "Impressive."
>
> ***And Chewbacca, at the very least, will be coming for Solo.* Fett nodded. "We might discuss my staying," he conceded.**

Jabba also requested Fett try to catch him a krayt dragon. Fett didn't seem as interested, but it seems to have been part of the arrangement because the Han Solo bounty was so high.

Answer (score 16):

[Boba Fett worked many jobs for Jabba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Canon#The_hunt_for_Han_Solo). The [starwars.com Databank entry for Boba Fett](http://www.starwars.com/databank/boba-fett) explains that Boba and Jabba had a long term working relationship:

> [Boba] became one of Jabba the Hutt’s go-to mercenaries, and was present during a tense meeting between the gangster and Han Solo...Boba remained one of Jabba the Hutt’s most trusted enforcers, and was **a fixture in the crime lord’s palace**.

Boba was likely visiting Jabba's palace on another assignment during the events of *Return of the Jedi*. He hadn't stayed simply to wait for the Rebels to attempt to rescue Han.

Comment: One of the novels mentioned that Jabba kept Fett available on retainer. In addition to the retainer, Fett had the run of the palace and any fuel/supplies he needed at a very significant discount. For Fett, it was a lucrative business arrangement.

Comment: @Omegacron Do you remember which novel? This would be a good alternate answer from Legends. I would upvote it.

Comment: I'd have to check (at work currently). It may have been either 'Tales of the Bounty Hunters' or 'Tales of Jabba's Palace' - those seem like the most likely suspects. It was a brief mention, but basically stated that the only downside for Fett was that the Hutt's jobs got priority. It may have also been in Shadows of the Empire (the novel, not the comic or game).

Comment: @Omegacron: It's in *Tales of the Bounty Hunters*, when Fett kills a teenage crime lord who tried to muscle in on Jabba's glitterstim trade. He began to deal with Jabba in *The Hutt Gambit*, when Jabba paid him to **not** kill Han Solo, who had a bounty on his head from one of Jabba's competitors. Fett agreed, temporarily, but reserved the right to pay Jabba back and collect the original bounty on Solo later. He began directly working for Jabba a short time later.